Nextjs14 Build error "window is not defined" occurs when using snapsvg-cjs-ts
I created an app using Nextjs 14 and snapsvg-cjs-ts. In development mode, I achieved my desired result. However, when attempting to create a build, I consistently received the error message "ReferenceError: window is not defined." So far, the only conclusion I have reached is that the error is directly connected to the line "const s = Snap(200, 100);".
Package.json 

  "dependencies": {
    "@prisma/client": "^5.12.1",
    "@radix-ui/react-dropdown-menu": "^2.0.6",
    "@radix-ui/react-navigation-menu": "^1.1.4",
    "@radix-ui/react-slider": "^1.1.2",
    "@radix-ui/react-slot": "^1.0.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^2.2.3",
    "@uidotdev/usehooks": "^2.4.1",
    "class-variance-authority": "^0.7.0",
    "clsx": "^2.1.0",
    "lucide-react": "^0.354.0",
    "next": "14.1.3",
    "next-themes": "^0.2.1",
    "react": "^18",
    "react-dom": "^18",
    "react-hook-form": "^7.51.1",
    "react-toastify": "^10.0.4",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "snapsvg-cjs-ts": "^0.0.6",
    "tailwind-merge": "^2.2.1",
    "tailwindcss-animate": "^1.0.7",
    "zustand": "^4.5.2"
  },

app/page.tsx


// import dynamic from "next/dynamic";
import { getCaracteres } from "./lib/action";

// import Coran from "./Coran/page";
import Lettre from "./Lettre/page";
// const Lettre = dynamic(() => import ( "./Lettre/page"),{ssr: false});

export default async function Home() {

  const resp = await getCaracteres()

  return (
    <Lettre />
  );
}

Lettre/page.tsx 


    useEffect(() => {
        console.log(window)
        if ((window !== undefined && window['Element'])) {
            console.log('after:', window)

            const target: any = document.getElementById("target") || null;
            target.innerHTML = ""

            const s = Snap(200, 100);
            s.transform("s8 t5 45")
            s.attr({ id: "dessin" })
            s.appendTo(target)
            s.addClass('svgClass')

            const ll = lettres[car]


            const svgLettre = s.path(
                ll?.path
            )
                .attr({ class: "pathClass" })
                .transform(`s${3 * ll?.scale}`)

            const lll = s.line(0, 0, 100, 100).addClass('lineRClass')
            const svgGroup = s.group(svgLettre, lll).transform(`t${ll.x + 10.4} ${ll.y - 88.83}`)


        }
    }, [car, newLettre])


npm run build

ReferenceError: window is not defined
    at 1782 (/root/coran/.next/server/chunks/413.js:1:3328)
    at t (/root/coran/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at 7518 (/root/coran/.next/server/app/page.js:1:6249)
    at t (/root/coran/.next/server/webpack-runtime.js:1:128)
    at F (/root/coran/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94693)
    at /root/coran/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97108
    at W._fromJSON (/root/coran/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:97546)
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at L (/root/coran/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:94414)
    at t (/root/coran/node_modules/next/dist/compiled/next-server/app-page.runtime.prod.js:12:100799)

Error occurred prerendering page "/Lettre". Read more: https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/prerender-error

I tried the three suggested methods:

1. typeof

if (window !== undefined) {
  // browser code
}

2. useEffect

3. Dynamic loading.


remove the line  console.log(window) and I hope it will work
